# How do I replace an item in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, onitemclicklistener

I have a listview which is populated by an array adpater. A user starts on activity a and after clicking an item in the listview is taken to activity b where they can edit the item they clicked. The edited item from B is sent back to A through an intent after the user returns to A. I want the original item clicked in A to be replaced with the data received from the intent from B.

```
ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    // setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


//intent receiving data from Activity B; I want to add in statement to change the original item clicked to this new String, edit;
    Bundle fromedit = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (fromedit != null) {
        String edit = fromedit.getString("BENG");
        int ps = fromedit.getInt("POSITION");

    }

//onclicklistener for the listview
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Notes.this, EditNote.class);

            intent.putExtra("KEY", values.get(position).toString());
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original activity you need to keep an int variable referring to the selected item index on the list. So your onItemClick() would look like that:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        currentSelected = position;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Notes.this, EditNote.class);

        intent.putExtra("KEY", values.get(position).toString());
        intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);

        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

When you return from the activity where you modify the data you need to update the item of your `values` list and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update your list by calling `mList.set(index, Object);` and then refreshing the Adapter to update ListView displayed data?

Comment: just      .set ? I don't see a method of only .set(index, Object)

Comment: it's available for ArrayList<T>. Try converting your 'values' to an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ArrayList#set() method, thus if your 'values' dataset is an ArrayList.

The java.util.ArrayList.set(int index, E element) replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

modify your code as follows:

```
//intent receiving data from Activity B; I want to add in statement to change the original item clicked to this new String, edit;

Bundle fromedit = getIntent().getExtras();
if (fromedit != null) {
    String edit = fromedit.getString("BENG");
    int ps = fromedit.getInt("POSITION");
    values.set(ps, edit);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```